# C makefile error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_main""

Tags: c, makefile

When I try to make I got this error :

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra ./libft/libft.a  -I./libft/ -I./includes/ -o server
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

But my server.c have main function.

My project's goal is to make small server-client program. So I try to make two target-Server and Client-at once. I try to find error but failed. How can I fix it?

Here is my Makefile :

```
CLIENT = client
SERVER = server

CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra

INC = -I$(LIBFT_DIR) -I$(HEADER_DIR)

LIBFT = $(LIBFT_DIR)libft.a
LIBFT_DIR = ./libft/

HEADER_DIR = ./includes/
HEADER_LIST = minitalk.h
HEADERS = $(addprefix $(HEADER_DIR), $(HEADER_LIST))

SRC_DIR = ./srcs/
SRC_S = server.c \
OBJ_S = $(OBJ_S:.c=.o)
SRC_C = client.c \
OBJ_C = $(OBJ_C:.c=.o)

all : $(SERVER) $(CLIENT)

$(SERVER) : $(LIBFT) $(OBJ_S)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(CLIENT) :$(LIBFT) $(OBJ_C)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c $(HEADER_LIST)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INC) $< -o $@

$(LIBFT):
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) all

clean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @rm $(OBJ_S) $(OBJ_C)

fclean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    @rm $(OBJ_S) $(OBJ_C)

bonus : all
```

---

Thank you for helpful advices, I modified my Makefile :

```
CLIENT = client
SERVER = server

CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra

INC = -I$(LIBFT_DIR) -I$(HEADER_DIR)

LIBFT = $(LIBFT_DIR)libft.a
LIBFT_DIR = ./libft/

HEADER_DIR = ./includes/
HEADER_LIST = minitalk.h
HEADERS = $(addprefix $(HEADER_DIR), $(HEADER_LIST))

SRC_DIR = ./srcs/
SRC_S = server.c \
#change definition of OBJ
OBJ_S = $(SRC_S:.c=.o)
SRC_C = client.c \
OBJ_C = $(SRC_C:.c=.o)

all : $(SERVER) $(CLIENT)

#added $(OBJ_S), $(OBJ_C)
$(SERVER) : $(LIBFT)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(OBJ_S)

$(CLIENT) :$(LIBFT)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(OBJ_C)

%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HEADERS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

$(LIBFT):
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) all

clean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @rm $(OBJ_S) $(OBJ_C)

fclean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    @rm $(OBJ_S) $(OBJ_C)

bonus : all
```

But same error still occurs. I trying to find problem through comparing command line compile string and my makefile. I will write here if solved.

---

I fixed it! The problem was '\' character in S_SRC/C_SRC definition.
It appends next line to current one. Here is the result :

```
S_SRC : server.c S_OBJ =
C_SRC : client.c C_OBJ =
```

Remove it, now my makefile works well.

Comment: `make` shows you the compilation command and that it is clearly missing `server.o`. For target `$(SERVER)`, `$(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@` probably needs to be `$(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(OBJ_S)`. Do the similar thing for target `$(CLIENT)`.

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Thank you so much! But same error still occurs. Maybe another problem exists.

Comment: If you get stuck just ask a separate question. I'm pretty sure you won't get stuck. Practice at the command line until you get it right, then codify it in the makefile.

Comment: Good idea. I will try that. Thank you for helping!

Comment: This is not a Makefile error, "make" just reports a follow-up error. The actual error is, as its message tells you, that there is not `main()` in the modules you link. You might want to correct the title and prose of your question, and add the changed Makefile after Jeff's comment, so we can follow what you have now. [Edit] your question for this, and remember to **add**, do not delete the old version.

Answer (score 3):

The question title suggests that you are focusing on the wrong part of the diagnostic message.  The key part is ...

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_main"
> ```

... which is reinforced by

> ```
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> ```

The issue is that you are attempting to build a program, but the linker does not see a `main()` function.  And why not?  The build output emitted by `make` shows that only the static library is being linked, whereas the makefile gives the impression that you intended to link a `server.o` as well.

It appears that `$(OBJ_S)` is expanding to nothing.  And why would *that* be?  Well, look at its (only) definition:

> ```
> OBJ_S = $(OBJ_S:.c=.o)
> ```

You are defining it in terms of its own (empty) previous value.  Presumably you meant

```
OBJ_S = $(SRC_S:.c=.o)
```

.  Similar applies to the client.

There may be other issues too.  In particular, if the sources are in `./srcs/` rather than in the same directory with the makefile, then your pattern rule will not do what you appear to want, for at least two distinct reasons.  It looks like what you actually want for that might be:

```
%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Note in particular the changes in the prerequisite list.  Although I also reordered the arguments on the compilation command line, that's more a matter of convention that of correct behavior.

Comment: Oh It's true. Some reason my code still reports same error. But this really helpful. Thanks alot!