How to compile a program built for MacOS-x86_64 on MacOS-Arm64
I'm getting this error message when I tried to compile "respknt" program under Rosetta 2 on my macOS-arm64 (apple silicon/M1 chip):
gfortran -g runtest.o runcmd.o -o bin//runtest
ld: warning: ignoring file runtest.o, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file runcmd.o, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [runtest] Error 1.
Please note that, "respknt" is a seismological software that is built on reflection matrix method of Kenneth 1986.
I switched the architecture on my Mac terminal from arm64 to MacOS x86_64 to test if I could compile the "respknt" program.
I even verified if I have switched the architecture to MacOS x86_64 by invoking the "gcc -v" command:
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin.
Also, I got "i386" when I invoked "arch" command.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your time!

This question is similar to: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70057202/62576). Please always search for error messages before posting. This question has been asked many, many times before.)

The relevant portion of the error you posted is in Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_main".

How were runtest.o and runcmd.o compiled? Are you using that GitHub repo that has object files and .DS_Store committed? If so, then my guess is that your gfortran is actually arm64-only and cannot produce Intel binaries.

@KenWhite different issue. The OP is neither failing to link against a library nor to supply the relevant object files on the command line - the error is due to the linker skipping the provided object files because there seems to be some mismatch on the selected target architecture.

@Siguza: Then please explain to me why a gold badge user used it as a reason to close this question that contains the same exact error message.

@KenWhite it's not the same error message. The one you link is an imported symbol referenced from main. That's failure to link against a library. The symptom here is main itself not being found, because all input files get skipped.
